# Android rooms TypeConveter not working

Tags: android, android-room

I have an `entity(table)` called `movies` with an `attribute(column)` called `subscriberEmails`.

```
@Entity(tableName = "movies")
public class DBMovies {
    ....
    private ArrayList<String> subscriberEmails;
    ....
}
```

I have used the following `TypeConverter` to save and retrieve the `ArrayList` to and from the database.

I am able to save the entity using the following `Query`

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void addList(DBMovies dBMovies );
```

However when I retrieve the `subscriberEmails` instead of getting an `ArrayList` of emails I am getting an `ArrayList` as shown in the image.

[image]

So rooms is not able to use the below `TypeConverter` to convert the String back to `ArrayList`.

```
@TypeConverter
public static String arrayListToString(ArrayList<String> listToBeConverted) {
    return gson.toJson(listToBeConverted);
}

@TypeConverter
public static ArrayList<String> stringToArrayList(String stringToBeConverted) {
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(stringToBeConverted, type);
}
```

`TypeConverter` is registered with the `AppDatabase` class

```
@Database(entities = {DBMovies.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@android.arch.persistence.room.TypeConverters({TypeConverters.class})
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase{
...
}
```

Comment: Where have you registered the `@TypeConverter` methods?

Comment: I edited the question, please check.

Comment: It's possible that this is a bug in Room, as AFAIK what you have should be OK. You might want to create a reproducible test case and [file an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:197448%20status:open).

Comment: Sure will do, the test case should be attached the rooms project?

Comment: Yes, as without a reproducible test case, it will be difficult for anyone to determine what may be going wrong. FWIW, in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-androidarch/tree/v0.4/General/RoomTypes), I have a similar set of transformers, going between `Set<String>` and `String`, and they seem to work fine, albeit in limited testing.

Comment: have you unit tested `arrayListToString` and `stringToArrayList` to make sure they work as intended?

Comment: @Benjamin Yeah I have unit tested em... There is no issue with the converters.